"1292 Incorrect datetime value" when updating a different field
There are a lot of great Stackoverflow questions/answers with regard to this error. However, most (all) are focused on updating the problem field itself. For example, a common solution is to set sql_mode to NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION (thus disabling strict mode) and then updating the field that currently has a 0000-00-00 value.
However, my issue is slightly different. I have a table with multiple date columns (often for the same record) containing malformed data (0000-00-00). If I run a query to update one column, I get this error thrown for one of the other columns -- regardless of what sql_mode I set or whether I use UPDATE IGNORE. It's as if the sql_mode only applies to the column I'm updating, but errors are still thrown for the other columns.
Here's a stripped down example:
Let's say I have a table with three columns: id, created_date, modified date, and I have this row:
id | created_date | modified date
---------------------------------
5  | 0000-00-00   | 0000-00-00

This query will error:
UPDATE mytable SET created_date = NULL WHERE id = 5;

and the error will be on the modified_date field.
If I update both fields, I get no error:
UPDATE mytable SET created_date = NULL, modified_date = NULL WHERE id = 5;

Again -- I'm setting the sql_mode to ensure I'm not in strict mode or have either NO_ZERO_DATE or NO_ZERO_IN_DATE enabled. Also note that I am running MySQL 8.
For various reasons I can't easily run updates that affect both columns -- I need to do a single column at a time. But can't seem to get around this error.

What if you do SET created_date = NULL, modified_date = modified_date?

The issue is that I need to be able to update a single column at a time, and for whatever reason, MySQL is "strict" about that, regardless of the sql_mode. I can update two columns at once without issue -- but I need to be able to do one at a time.

For all the columns you don't need to update, use columnname=columnname to keep it the same.

Do you have any triggers on this table by any chance?

It was the Triggers! @JorgeCampos -- thanks for the tip!

Happy to be of help!

I've added it as an answer as it might help others in the future.

I will add this as an answer as it might help others and it was suggested on the comments section.
Whenever you are running DML (insert, update, deletes) scripts and the data is acting up or you are receiving errors that doesn't look related to the script you are running, always check whether you have triggers associated to the table.
This was the case of OP here.
